# Durandal 2.0: Bind shell subnav to current child router

Tags: durandal

My app can be considered as a collection of Sections and Subsections.  My end goal is to have a shell with the main navbar mapped to each Section and another 'sub' navbar beneath that is a tabbed navigation mapping to the Subsections of the currently selected Section.  I also don't (yet?) have a need for a page to show for any Section; that is, only one of the Subsection pages is shown when you navigate to a Section.

In the previous version of Durandal, I retrieved all the current users' available (based on permissions) Sections and Subsections after logon.  I then added each individual Subsection as a route using the mapRoute function on the router.  I also extended the router with observable collections of Sections and Subsections, which were bound to the shell navbars.

For Durandal 2.0, how do I bind elements on the shell to a child router?  Do I and can I create all the necessary child routers as soon as my logon operation is complete and I have the list of all Sections and Subsections that are available to the user?

Please let me know if this question doesn't make sense or needs more information.  Thank you.

Comment: Where are you creating the child router?

Comment: The examples all create child routers in the activate function of the modules' viewModels.  I was looking to create them all at once based on the Sections and Subsections returned after login.  I guess I need to create them all and then have an observable on the main router of the current childRouter's visible routes.

Comment: I also guess I could bind the shell subnav tabs to an app-level observable which I then update on activation of a module.  I'll work on that see what I can come up with.